# Why my Async method is not called from another screen using functional component in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to store data in Reducers file by calling Action file from my
The login screen is implemented using function components.

I can't get the point where I was mistaken and why I can't able to call the action file from my login screen.
so please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is some code of my files

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../Actions';
import { Images } from '../Helpers/imageConstants';
import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import {
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { InputText } from '../Components/inputText';
import { ButtonTouch } from '../Components/button';
import { SignInUser } from '../Actions/authAction';
import { showMessage } from 'react-native-flash-message';

const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isCheck, ischecked] = useState(false);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
  const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmitPress = () => {
    if (!userEmail) {
      showMessage({
        message: 'Please Enter Your Email',
        type: 'danger',
      });
    } else if (!userPassword) {
      showMessage({
        message: 'Please Enter Your Password',
        type: 'danger',
      });
    } else {
      console.log('comes in else');
      SignInUser({ userEmail, userPassword });
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image source={Images.imageLogo} style={styles.imgLogo} />

        <View style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
          <InputText
            Placeholder={'Email'}
            PlaceholderTextcolor={'#000'}
            onChangeText={(userEmail) => setUserEmail(userEmail)}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <InputText
            Placeholder={'Password'}
            PlaceholderTextcolor={'#000'}
            onChangeText={(userPassword) => setUserPassword(userPassword)}
            SecureTextEntry={true}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.checkPwdView}>
          <CheckBox
            isChecked={isCheck}
            style={styles.checkVw}
            rightText={'Remeber Me'}
            rightTextStyle={styles.rightChekBoxText}
            onClick={() => {
              ischecked(!isCheck);
            }}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.forgotPwdTouch}>
            <Text style={styles.forgotText}> Forgot Password ?</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginBottom: 60 }}>
          <ButtonTouch onPress={handleSubmitPress} title={'Login'} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.dontAcntVw}>
          <TouchableHighlight>
            <Text style={styles.dontAcntTxt}>Dont have an account? </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.signUpTxt}> Signup here</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Login;

let LoginComponent = connect(actions)(Login);
export { LoginComponent };
```

**authAction.js**

```
import { usersArrayData } from '../Helpers/usersArrayData';
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from '../Actions/type';

export const SignInUser = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log('log :--', email, password);
  var userData = { data: usersArrayData };
  console.log('come inn');
  usersArrayData.filter((item) => {
    console.log('come inn22222', usersArrayData);
    if (item.emailid === email && item.pass === password) {
      console.log('userdata===>>>', userData);

      return dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: userData });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

**authReducer.js**

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from "../Actions/type"

const INITIAL_STATE = {userData:[]}

const authReducer= (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, userData: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default authReducer ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may add SignInUser in object function dispatch like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  SignInUser,
};
let LoginComponent = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
export { LoginComponent };
```

Comment: Hmm do you need async (dispatch) because I don't see any await in your function?

Comment: Ya you are right i am not using await in my function.so can you please tell me another way for solve this issue.Because still this function is not called.@Anhdevit

Comment: SignInUser(userEmail, userPassword) not  SignInUser({ userEmail, userPassword });

Comment: I did that but still same issue any another way ?@Anhdevit

Comment: In your code, you define a function like that SignInUser = (email, password). Hmmm. Could you so your reducer?

Comment: ya sure, please see above i edited my post .@Ahndevit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223277/discussion-between-raghu-singh-and-anhdevit).

Comment: I think I find solution dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: userData }) should be dispatch(() => ({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: userData }))